# Use max by in PromQL query while keeping a label that is not part of the "by"

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm trying to join two metrics (`build_status` and `build_timestamp`) and then filter out duplicates based on a specific labels (`service` and `timestamp`).
This is what I came up with:

```
max by (service, timestamp) (
  build_status{stage="$stage", envId="$env"} * on(stage, env, service, status) 
    group_left(timestamp) build_timestamp{stage="$stage", env="$env"}
)
```

This works well, except that the `status` label is then lost, and I can bring it back if I add it to the `max by` (i.e.: `max by (service, timestamp, status)`) but then I get duplicates, for example:

> service1 timestamp1 status1
> service1 timestamp1 status2

How do I max by the service and timestamp but keep the status label?
Thanks!

Comment: How come you have different states for same build? Also which of two (or more?) you hope to save?

Comment: And moreover, why do you have both metric status, and label status?

Comment: @markalex there are different metrics that are being reported per build, it's not just one "build metric" with various labels, and it's not in my control. The status metric has more labels other than the actual status, and that also is out of my control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Prometheus' [original documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators):

> `topk` and `bottomk` are different from other aggregators in that a subset
> of the input samples, including the original labels, are returned in
> the result vector. `by` and `without` are only used to bucket the input
> vector.

So you can use topk for your case:

```
 topk by(service, timestamp) (1,
  build_status{stage="$stage", envId="$env"} * on(stage, env, service, status) 
    group_left(timestamp) build_timestamp{stage="$stage", env="$env"}
)
```

[More info](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/)

Comment: Thanks!
I already went in another direction, but this seems like a great solution. Unfortunately the bounty is over though :/